# IIS ASP Caching

Tags: iis, caching, asp-classic

I'm trying to configure ASP caching in IIS, following the instructions of a software I purchased. This is supposed to make it run faster.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a5766228-828e-4e31-a92b-51da7d24d569.mspx?mfr=true

The software instructions point to that article.

The problem i'm having is that the "**ASP File Cache** section" that's mentioned there does not exist in my IIS dialog...

Am I missing something?
Is there any configuration that'll make it appear?
I'm running IIS 6.0 on W2003 Server Enterprise Edition.

Update 1: I am logged in as the local administrator (the box is not in a domain)

Comment: Are you an admin on that box?

Comment: Yes, I am logged in as the local administrator (the box is not in a domain)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on "Web sites" in IIS manager. Choose Properties->Home directory->Configuration and you'll see "Cache options" tab.

The trick is to click on "Web sites" as opposed to proceeding to specific web site.