# Flush cache in iis6

Tags: iis, caching, iis-6

For some magical reason ii6 started to cache pages on the server. Even if I remove the page, it is still displayed. I tried to follow couple suggestions but no luck. 
That's what I did so far:

1. Deleted \WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
2. Unchecked 'cache ISAPI extensions' in the IIS configuration.
3. Added 'Cache-Control no-cache' to HTTP headers in properties.
4. Tried to create the page that clear the cache http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/13/67641.aspx

Update: also tried to disable asp cache 
[IIS ASP Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103158/iis-asp-caching)
But the files in v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files are still created

If anybody has other suggestions, please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replies guys.

I figured out that it wasn't the caching issue. I didn't cleared out Bin folder and the compiled version of the page with extension .compiled was seating there all the time. I don't what changed this time, but I followed the same process like 100 times before and copied files on top without clearing Bin.

I should be more accurate with such things.

Answer (score 3):

Please give the delete permission for IIS user on below folder. these files will be deleted automatically by IIS

For 64 bit OS folder path:
\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 2):

My classic ASP pages WOULD NOT refresh from any browser. Finally, stopping and starting the IIS service (IIS6) fixed the problem.

You, too, can go bonkers, just like me. Simply have IIS start giving out stale pages! A bargain at half the price!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try restarting the IIS server to see if that stops it from displaying? If it doesn't, then it might not be a caching issue.

I believe restarting the server is supposed to clear the cache.

Comment: Yes, I restarted iis after each change

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem isn't the IIS, but a web proxy between your browser and your web server caching the page?

Or a wrong DNS settings pointing to another server which holds a copy of that web/page? You could also look on the same IIS if there is another web configured and host headers got mixed up, making you test on the wrong web.

Answer (score 0):

I might just say the obvious here but have you tried recycling the application pool?